# Expanding Activity URN within the Share API

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to expand the `activity` URN within a share retrieved by the Share API.

Here's my API request (notice the activity~ in the end):

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:person:lKq9OL3DMf&sortBy=LAST_MODIFIED&sharesPerOwner=100&projection=(elements*(*, activity~))
```

However, this is what I'm getting:

```
"elements": [
        {
            "activity!": {
                "message": "URN Resolution failed for unknown reasons.: com.linkedin.r2.RemoteInvocationException: GatewayException{_serviceErrorCode=null}",
                "status": 500
            },
            "owner": "urn:li:person:lKq9OL3DMf",
            "activity": "urn:li:activity:6829030971896074240",
            "edited": false,
            "created": {
                "actor": "urn:li:person:lKq9OL3DMf",
                "time": 1628167860945
            },
            "distribution": {
                "linkedInDistributionTarget": {
                    "visibleToGuest": true
                }
            },
            "clientApp": "urn:li:developerApplication:4086541",
            "text": {
                "text": "Testing scheduled date draft NEW PROFILE"
            },
            "id": "6829030971568918528",
            "lastModified": {
                "actor": "urn:li:csUser:0",
                "time": 1628167861021
            }
        },
    ...
]
```

If I try to get the activity's details (likes and comments) through the socialActions API, it does work indeed:

API Call:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/socialActions/urn:li:activity:6810873575264829440
```

API Response:

```
{
    "commentsSummary": {
        "totalFirstLevelComments": 1,
        "aggregatedTotalComments": 5
    },
    "$URN": "urn:li:activity:6810873575264829440",
    "likesSummary": {
        "aggregatedTotalLikes": 1,
        "likedByCurrentUser": false,
        "totalLikes": 1
    },
    "target": "urn:li:activity:6810873575264829440"
}
```

May I know why I cannot expand the activity URN within the share API? It clearly works if I fetch it through socialActions

Thanks.